# Phoenix alter table add column fails

Tags: sql, hbase, apache-phoenix, sqlline

I am trying to add a column to an existing phoenix table using alter table command as below

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD "db_name" VARCHAR(20);
```

Its failing with below warning

```
WARN query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: Unable to update meta data repo within 1 seconds for TABLE1
```

Let me know, If there is any timeout I need to increase to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

When altering a table, Phoenix will by default check with the server to ensure it has the most up to date table metadata and statistics. This RPC may not be necessary when you know in advance that the structure of a table may never change. The UPDATE_CACHE_FREQUENCY property was added in Phoenix 4.7 to allow the user to declare how often the server will be checked for meta data updates. You can set this property on your table like below

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 SET UPDATE_CACHE_FREQUENCY=900000
```

Please refer this doc for [tuning](https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning_guide.html) tips.

Comment: I created table with UPDATE_CACHE_FREQUENCY to 30 mins as well as NEVER (As i know the schema), but still my alter fails with same timeout warning